# UIsplitviewcontroller's back button not responding correctly

Tags: ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I am creating an app in which it shows first master view with 6 buttons are present. any of button tab it navigate to another view controller in which i have added a split view controller programmatically. In the split view controller's right view controller contain navigation bar with custom back button. when i press the back button it must be navigate to master view controller. but it is not working currectly.

[image: split view based image]

i have used the code for back button is

```
-(void)backBtnTap:(id)sender
```

{
  [[self tabBarController] setSelectedIndex:0];
  [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
  [(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] backLoadData];
}

In the AppDelegate Method

```
-(void)backLoadData
```

{

```
[self.tabBarController.view removeFromSuperview];
[self.window reloadInputViews];
[self.window addSubview:self.tabBarController.view];
```

}

Please help me to find such a solution

Thanx in Advance

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:** finally i have founded solution. I added the root view controller in my window in it's work perfectly.